# OpenCV requires Android SDK Tools revision 14 or newer

Tags: python, android, opencv, kivy, apk

I'm trying to developing apk via Python Kivy and OpenCV in Ubuntu 16.04. My script works on Windows/Ubuntu and also  `buildozer android debug deploy run` is successful, but when I try to open apk on phone, it close immediately.
Buildozer.spec:

```
[app]
title = Prj
package.name = proje
package.domain = org.ylc
source.dir = .
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas
version = 0.1
requirements =  kivy, numpy, opencv
orientation = landscape
```

When I commented `import cv2` in my script, it opens on android phone. I couldn't understand where I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.